# Dropbox synch, 1 file missing, how identify the file?

Tags: windows, sync, dropbox, utility

I just synched Drobox between my old Windows 10 laptop (the source) and my new Window 11 desktop (the target). I then did a Windows Properties on the Dropbox folder on both machines.

On the source:

273,345 Files, 32,878 Folders

On the target:

273,344 Files, 32,878 Folders

So there's one less file on the target. Is there a quick and easy way for me to identify the file that wasn't synched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember about Dropbox, it used to keep old versions of every file under `.dropbox` instead of immediately deleting them, as well as storing temporary sync files there. This subfolder needs to be excluded from your count, otherwise the numbers will be inaccurate.

Open Command Prompt, `cd/d` to your Dropbox, then do

```
dir/a/b/on/s | sort > C:\Users\foo\Desktop\filelist.txt
```

to get a list of files. Do it on both systems, then use any diff tool (e.g. `fc` or `git diff`) to compare them.

Comment: Your command works on Windows 10. For some reason on Windows 11 I get "Access is denied."  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I got it to work by running cmd as Administrator on Windows 11. Now to work on the diff...

Comment: Using Windows fc I found the culprit. It's an empty temporary Open Office file that should have been deleted, but wasn't: ~$taracts.odt